# Code analysis issue in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, httprequest, code-analysis

Please find the below code:

```
private static void HandleValidationError(ILogger logger, HttpRequestMessage requestMessage, HttpStatusCode statusCode, string message)
        {
        logger.LogError(LoggingSources.API, message);
throw new HttpResponseException(requestMessage.CreateErrorResponse(statusCode, message));
   }
            }
```

I am getting the below CA issue :

> CA2000    Dispose objects before losing scope In method
>   'ControllerHelper.HandleValidationError(ILogger, HttpRequestMessage,
>   HttpStatusCode, string)', object
>   'HttpRequestMessageExtensions.CreateErrorResponse(requestMessage,
>   statusCode, message)' is not disposed along all exception paths. Call
>   System.IDisposable.Dispose on object
>   'HttpRequestMessageExtensions.CreateErrorResponse(requestMessage,
>   statusCode, message)' before all references to it are out of
>   scope.    Tasks.Application.Web.API   ControllerHelper.cs 106

Caller of the above function is:

```
public static void CheckForValidDelimitedIntegerInput(ILogger logger, HttpRequestMessage request, char delimiter, string input)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
            {
                try
                {
                    string[] idList = input.Split(delimiter);
                    for (int i = 0; i < idList.Length; i++)
                    {
                        int result;
                        if (!int.TryParse(idList[i], out result) || result <= 0)
                        {
                            HandleValidationError(logger, request, HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, InvalidIntegerOrShort);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (HttpResponseException)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                HandleValidationError(logger, request, HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, InvalidParameter);
            }
        }
```

I tried the stackoverflow earlier post [Do I need to dispose an HttpResponseException from Request.CreateResponse()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20688999/do-i-need-to-dispose-an-httpresponseexception-from-request-createresponse) But it did not work out.

Comment: You don't need to call `Dispose` in the `finally` block.  It's wrapped in a `using`, it'll get disposed.

Comment: Yeah I know. But still I am getting the same CA issue.

Comment: Are you sure you want to dispose `requestMessage` in the method?  It's being passed in; shouldn't the calling method handle the life cycle?

Comment: You are disposing the `HttpRequestMessage` passed to the method, but you are not disposing the `HttpRequestMessage`  created by calling `requestMessage.CreateErrorResponse`.

Comment: Maybe put `logger.LogError(LoggingSources.API, message);` inside the try block.

Comment: I have updated the question. Do you guys have any solution ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do I need to dispose an HttpResponseException from Request.CreateResponse()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20688999/do-i-need-to-dispose-an-httpresponseexception-from-request-createresponse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after some analysis I found the answer.

```
private static void HandleValidationError(ILogger logger, HttpRequestMessage requestMessage, HttpStatusCode statusCode, string message)
    {
        logger.LogError(LoggingSources.API, message);
        using (var errorResponse = requestMessage.CreateErrorResponse(statusCode, message))
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(errorResponse);
        }
    }
```

This will fix the CA issue. And also I want to appreciate John for his help.

Comment: Is it possible that you could still be accessing `errorResponse` when handling his exception later?  If that's the case, then it's possible that this will throw an exception when it tries to access the disposed object.

Comment: hmmm yeah but that case will not apply here I think.

Answer (score 1):

Read [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.110).aspx) to understand the "Dispose Pattern".  Also, read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085939/who-should-call-dispose-on-idisposable-objects-when-passed-into-another-object) to see when an object should be disposed.  In your particular case, it looks like an [anti-pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern) to dispose an argument to a function, when the caller still has a reference to it.

To address the warning that you are getting, `requestMessage.CreateErrorResponse(...)` creates an `HttpResponseMessage`, which implements `IDisposable`.  This is falling out of scope (because there are no references you make to it), before the method returns.  This means the code analysis tool sees that `Dispose` on this object is never called.

EDIT:

To fix this issue, simply remove the `using` directive, and simplify your code as follows.

```
private static void HandleValidationError(ILogger logger, HttpRequestMessage requestMessage, HttpStatusCode statusCode, string message)
{
    logger.LogError(LoggingSources.API, message);
    throw new HttpResponseException(requestMessage.CreateErrorResponse(statusCode, message));
}
```

This seemed to work for me.  This will leave disposing the objects to the caller, though.

EDIT:

Aha!  I found this [stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20688999/do-i-need-to-dispose-an-httpresponseexception-from-request-createresponse) which seems to be your exact issue.  For completeness, it basically says that you don't need to dispose of the `HttpResponseMessage` object.  However, if you use the constructor instead, there is already a suppression of this warning so you don't need to suppress it yourself.

Try this:

```
private static void HandleValidationError(ILogger logger, HttpRequestMessage requestMessage, HttpStatusCode statusCode, string message)
{
    logger.LogError(LoggingSources.API, message);
    throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(statusCode){
        ReasonPhrase = message
    });
}
```

Note: because I could not reproduce this issue I was unable to test to make sure that this works.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Is there any other solution instead of Suppressing this error in Suppression file ?

Comment: It is not working. I have updated the question with the Caller function. Let me know if you have any answer

Comment: Are you getting the same code analysis error as before?

Comment: Thanks a lot John. I appreciate your help in this.

Answer (score 1):

Using `using` makes it 500 Internal Server error.

My solution is `RegisterForDispose` so it becomes:

```
var errorResponse = requestMessage.CreateErrorResponse(statusCode, message));
this.request.RegisterForDispose(errorResponse);
throw new HttpResponseException(errorResponse);
```

You still need to suppress the CA2000 warning, but I believe this is the right way to dispose, so the CA2000 needs to allow this dispose pattern.

Comment: You can exclude types and derived types in editorconfig, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2000

dotnet_code_quality.CA2000.excluded_type_names_with_derived_types = HttpRequestMessage